# Why must P/Invoke functions be static in C#?

Tags: c#

see the code:

```
class VirtualMemoryManager
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",EntryPoint="GetCurrentProcess")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcessHandle();
}
```

Why  the "GetCurrentProcessHandle" must "static"

Comment: For what reason are you asking the question? I propose a counter question: for what reason do you need it to *not* be static?

Comment: @Codesleuth, I'm betting the reason is: He doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> This is a requirement for P/Invoke methods because there is no consistent notion of an instance in the Windows API.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Externally imported functions are static by nature. By not making them static they will not gain anything. An instance method can use local variables, which is impossible with dll import routines anyway.